# is refreshing the page can kill the emitted values between components, and what can I do Instead

Tags: angular, angular5

my application consists of:

- root module.
- master-page Feature module (header, side-nav-bar, footer, full-screen-overlay navigator)
- Feature Module x ( which is the default module that her main component should 
  be displayed once the user logged in)
- Feature Module y (I can navigate to this module by selecting it from full-screen-overlay navigator)

what I'm trying to do is when ever the user tries to navigate throw the full-screen-overlay navigator I should send some data from the navigator component  to another component belongs to another module. 
the process of emitting value is fine, but the emitted value is not reaching to the destination component (parent component) after the page is refreshed (because of the routing), I'm not sure that this is right diagnoses, so here is the code:

```
 // html
.....
       <a [href]="link.href" (click)="sendModuleName(link.module_name)"> {{link.name}}</a>
....
```

// type script

```
import { Component, OnInit,Inject ,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef,MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-full-screen-overlay',
  templateUrl: './full-screen-overlay.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./full-screen-overlay.component.css']
})
export class FullScreenOverlayComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onModuleSelect = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FullScreenOverlayComponent>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  closeOverlayWindow(){
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
  sendModuleName(module_name:string){
     this.onModuleSelect.emit(module_name);
     console.log("the value has been emited",module_name);
  }

}
```

the parent component

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="openOverlayWindow()" (onModuleSelect)="onModuleSelect($event)"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>



 onModuleSelect(module_name:string){
         console.log('receiving value from overlay component:',module_name);

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at [Angular routing](https://angular.io/guide/router). If you build custom routing, you can use the `routerLink` directive instead of `href`, which doesn't reload the page. If you save your data in an Angular [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), you can retrieve the data from the linked page.

First, you need to build a custom router in your app module file (see link above for a tutorial), which can look something like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'somelink', component: SomeComponent },
  { path: 'someotherlink', component: AnotherComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    )
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

<sub>(copied from the tutorial)</sub>

And then you can use `routerLink` in place of `href` in your HTML:

```
<a [routerLink]="link.href" (click)="sendModuleName(link.module_name)"> {{link.name}}</a>
```

where `link.href` will be `'somelink'` or `'someotherlink'` in the router.

---

Edit: Also, a crash course on services:

Services allow you to share data between different components, and can run throughout the entire application.

Say, for example, you wanted to be able to access a variable called `applicationName` from any component, even when you changed pages using ther router (`routerLink`). If you created a service like this: (`exampleService.service.ts`):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  // say you want to access this variable on any component
  public applicationName: string;

}
```

Then you can *inject* it into any of your components like this:

```
import ExampleService from './example.service.ts';

@Component()
class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) {

    // access applicationName
    console.log(exampleService.applicationName);

    // set applicationName
    exampleService.applicationName = 'someValue';

  }
}
```

You can do this from any component, and `ExampleService`'s `applicationName` will be shared for all components.

Comment: thank you, do I need to use services even if I used routerLink?

Comment: @FurqanShakir I mentioned services because I imagine you'll be changing pages (and components) in Angular. Because the components change, the component's data won't persist. Angular services are a way to share data between different components, so it'll last even if you route to a different page.

Comment: @FurqanShakir No problem! And if you need help with the services, just let me know and I'll add a little explanation on this answer.

Comment: thank you, an example will be great, since I didn't used services for this purpose yet, I only used them to get/ post data from/to a back end server.